# Motion gives digital zoomed image on raspberry pi

Tags: zooming, webcam, raspberry-pi, motion

I've installed program "motion" on Raspbian OS in my Raspberry Pi to work with camera
The only thing that I couldn't understand is why it gives maximum zoomed image from my Creative PD1110 webcam. In motion.conf config file nothing about that directly. Maybe problem with v4l? I'm total newbee in linux. In windows on Skype all is perfect

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed that. I set resolution of image on 352x288 as by default in motion.conf (was 320x240). Still don't understand why it worked

Comment: Could someone else propose another fix to this issue?  I am getting the same problem with the digitally zoomed image using motion on a raspberry pi (raspian), however, setting the resolution to 352x288 did not solve my problem.  Is there any command line option I can change to set the default zoom of my webcam?  Is it a v4l issue?  Any way to fix separate from the motion service perhaps?